# Read a file in buffer then write buffer in new file

Tags: c

I am kind of new to filing operations used in C. I want to read a file, copy its content to a buffer, and then copy the contents from that buffer to a new file. (The purpose is for usage of this buffer in another task)
I am using the code below for reading my file in a buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
    FILE * fileP;
    long size;
    char * buffer;
    size_t final;

    fileP= fopen ( "C:\\Users\\test.pdf" , "rb" );
    if (fileP==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); 
    exit (1);
    }

    // calculating file size
    fseek (fileP, 0 , SEEK_END);
    size = ftell (fileP);
    rewind (fileP);

    // allocating mem for file
    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

    // copying file into buffer
    final = fread (buffer,1,size,fileP);
    if (final != size) 
    {
        fputs ("Reading error",stderr); 
        exit (3);
    }
    // the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. 

    fclose (fileP);
    free (buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

I know I need to use fwrite for writing the contents of buffer in to a new file, but I can't seem to get which parameters would be written in it. Or is there any better solution for it?

Comment: You'll be happy to hear that you can use the *exact same parameters* as in `fread`!

Comment: You write into the new file just like you are reading from the old file. i.e. you should use `fwrite` to write the file.

Comment: @RadLexus you mean fwrite would be this?
fwrite (buffer,1,size,fileP)

Comment: Create a new file using mode "w" or "wb" (Say fileQ), and then write the buffer into it using fwrite(buffer,1,sizeof(buffer),fileQ).

Comment: regarding this line: `buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*size);`  1) in C, do not cast the returned value from any of the heap memory allocation function (malloc, calloc, realloc) as it has type `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer. casting just clutters the code.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as ` and multiplying by 1 has no effect

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts. Never use tabs because each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set for individual preferences

Answer (score 2):

Jane,

Before you can `fwrite` anything, you first need to `fopen` the destination file.

[Source File] ---> [Memory Buffer] ---> [Destination File]

The classic sequence for writing a memory buffer to a file looks like this:

```
// Open File for writing
FILE *f_dst = fopen("C:\\foo.txt", "wb");
if(f_dst == NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR - Failed to open file for writing\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Write Buffer
if(fwrite(buffer, 1, size, f_dst) != size)
{
    printf("ERROR - Failed to write %i bytes to file\n", size);
    exit(1);
}

// Close File
fclose(f_dst);
f_dst = NULL;
```

Also, I noticed in your code around your `fread`, your are confusing 'result' and 'final' variables ('result' does not exist) :

> ```
> // copying file into buffer
> final = fread (buffer,1,size,fileP);
> if (result != size)
> ```

Comment: Yes the result variable was mistakenly used, I've edited my question now. I shall try what you answered, then will comment further

Comment: This worked, thank you. However  do you know how can I extract header of a .docx file? @Eresse

Comment: @Jane, I am not familiar with microsoft document formats. However, I think your best option is to ask this in a new question.